Azure Data Factory (ADF) trying to delete a csv file. Error Invalid delete activity payload with 'folderPath' that is required and cannot be empty
I have created a dataset which dynamically defines a .csv file.

Later on, in the false part of an if activity I try to copy the csv from one directory into a container to another directory in the same container and then delete the csv from the original dir.
The copy activity works fine using something like this to define the filepath:
@concat(variables('some_variable'),'/',pipeline().parameters.file_name)
After the copy I try to delete the above mentioned csv using the exact same filepath as above.
I receive the error message:
Invalid delete activity payload with 'folderPath' that is required and cannot be empty.

I dont see what folderPath is complaining about:




ADLS is a little different than traditional storage. Your dataset does not specify which filesystem (container) to connect to. When referencing a dynamic file in an ADLS dataset, you should include file system (container), directory (folder path) and file name parameters:

Then assign them in the connection:

You can hard code values like container if the dataset will only ever be used for that container.

Thanks @Joel, you are right. Im still wondering why the copy activity was working properly with the same provided filePath, though.
